# Splinter: ImportError: cannot import name Browser

Tags: python, selenium, automation, python-import, splinter

I am new to Splinter but I have used python few times. So I was hoping to automate a website using splinter. But I get the "ImportError: cannot import name Browser" error when I execute it.

Here is my code.

```
from splinter import Browser

browser = Browser()
browser.visit('http://google.com')
browser.fill('q', 'splinter - python acceptance testing for web applications')
browser.find_by_name('btnG').click()

if browser.is_text_present('splinter.readthedocs.org'):
    print "Yes, the official website was found!"
else:
    print "No, it wasn't found... We need to improve our SEO techniques"

browser.quit()
```

In terminal this is what I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "splinter.py", line 3, in <module>
    from splinter import Browser
  File "/var/www/project/splinter.py", line 3, in <module>
    from splinter import Browser
ImportError: cannot import name Browser
```

How can I run this program without any error?
I have referred solutions for similar issues like deleting splinter.pyc but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a local file named `splinter.py` , which is shadowing the library `splinter` as can be seen from the traceback -

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File **"splinter.py"**, line 3, in 
>      from splinter import Browser

Rename that file , you should not name your python files or packages in a way that would shadow/mask the libraries.